# React equivalent to ejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im used to do this kind of code using ejs, is there an equivalent way of doing this using react?

What Im trying:
I need to create a new  to each aux.Complements elements, the problem is that I cant do {return complement.title} inside html elements

```
{item.ComplementCategories.map(aux => {
    aux.Complements.map(complement => {
        <tr>
            <td>
                {complement.title}
            </td>
        </tr>
    })
})}
```

What I get:
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Comment: you need a `return` statement for `map` callback, is it works on ejs?

Comment: So your trying to using template content (`.ejs`) within JSX?

Comment: @DennisVash I need to create a new <tr> to each aux.Complements elements, the problem is that I cant do {return complement.title} inside html elements

Comment: You need to return the JSX element, have you tried reading the getting started section in React docs?

Comment: @DennisVash Yes Im kinda lost there, If I just try {return complement.title} without no html elements it works perfectly

Comment: Show full example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash posted an answer based on what you said about return the JSX element, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @DennisVash comment I came up with the following solution

```
    item.ComplementCategories.map(aux => {
        return aux.Complements.map(complement => {
            return <tr className="tableList--complements">
                <td className="text-left">
                    {complement.title}
                </td>
                <td className="text-center"> - </td>
                <td className="text-right">
                    R$ {complement.price_un}
                </td>
                <td className="text-center">
                    {complement.quantity}X
                </td>
                <td className="text-right">
                    -
                </td>
                <td className="text-right">
                    -
                </td>
            </tr>
        })
    })
```

Returned a html element and accessing the data through {}
Can also [Help](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/how+to+create+html+in+reactjs+map)